# Is it possible in TestCafe to expect errors to be thrown?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

With `t.skipJsError()` I can easily skip (specified) JS errors.

Is there also the possibility to expect, if a certain error has been thrown? That would mean, that if the error is not thrown, the test will not succeed.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to check that a JavaScript error occurs on the test page?

Comment: @mlosev exactly, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try-catch construction. For example:

```js
fixture('My fixture')
    .page('./index.html');
test('First test', async t => {
  try {
    await t.click('button');
  } catch (e) {
    await t.expect(e.errStack).contains('Error:');
  }
});
```